# After update Android Studio to 0.4.2 (0.4.5 just minutes) I get errors with gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After update Android Studio to 0.4.2 (and just minutes) 0.4.5, this message:

"01:51:28 PM Gradle 'xxxxxproyect' project refresh failed:
            A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
            : Gradle settings"

I worked with one of the initial versions of Android Studio, without updating regularly, today decided to, after upgrade this constant error not only ongoing projects but with greenfield projects without code appears .....

Run from Windows 7 (64bit) 
JDK 1.7.0

The problem seems to be with Gradle and is really persistent .....

What could check to solve this issue?

Comment: NEWS: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: NEWS: Set Gradle VM Options to: -Xms512m ....and restart ... didn't work!

Comment: include your build.gradle files in question.

Comment: I had same issue after upgrade. It appears to be a Gradle compatibility issue. My solution was to recreate project anew right in the new version of Android Studio.

Comment: I performed the same procedure you mention and create a new project Gradle seems to stay "cycling" with the update message in progress .... but nothing happens. It just stays there ...... I had not had problems before with android studio. I feel a little frustrated ......